# Issue with Ajax is not being called

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax

I am a beginner learning Ajax and javascript. After hours trying to find out whats was the problem, I gave up and brought the issue here. In tutorials from W3 schools, ajax works fine. My code has a form with a list and an input box. I want to collect the item selected in the list and the text entered in the input box. Then when a button is clicked, a function with ajax is called. It seems that my function is not being recognized or the function does nothing. The code is bellow. I wll be grateful on any light on this. Thank you.

```js
function showCustomer() {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var selcriteria = document.getElementById('tcriteria');
  var selcriteriavalue = selcriteria.options[selcriteria.selectedIndex].value;
  var criteriavalue = document.getElementById('bananas').value;
  alert(selcriteriavalue + ' ' + criteriavalue);

  xhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "action_page.py?tycriteria=" + tcriteria + "&vacriteria=" + vcriteria);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<h2>Get Contact using Ajax </h2>
<form action="">
  <select name="tcriteria">
    <option value="">Select a criteria:</option>
    <option value="Name">Name</option>
    <option value="Phone 1 - Value">Telephone</option>
    <option value="Notes">Notes</option>
  </select>
  <input type='text' id='apples' value=''>
  <button type="button" id="bananas" onclick="showCustomer()">Get info</button>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint">Contact data will be shown here...</div>
```

Comment: There is no element with the ID "tcriteria" for `document.getElementById('tcriteria')`. So referencing `selcriteria.options[selcriteria.selectedIndex].value` causes the error "Cannot read property 'options' of null". You might consider `<select name="tcriteria" id="tcriteria">`.

Comment: `vcriteria` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your line 3 you are trying to get element with id `tcriteria`:

`var selcriteria = document.getElementById('tcriteria');`

But there isnt any element with that id so you need to replace it with this:

`var selcriteria = document.querySelector('[name="tcriteria"]');`

Note: If you don't need support for very old browsers you can use `fetch` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`, use `${var} text ${var2}` (only in backticks) instead of tens of `+`-s and `let`-s and `const`-s instead of `var`-s. You can also use arrow functions.